# Отключить jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как отключить jquery-1.11.1.min.js, если он загружается через cdn? Из-за него не работают некоторые плагины.

Пробовал `wp_deregister_script( 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' );`, не поиомогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В документации ясно сказано - аргумент у deregister_script - это handle, а не путь к скрипту.

Comment: Покажите, как вызов выглядит в коде страницы (Ctrl+U) или дайте ссылку на сайт.

Comment: в самом конце страницы без id https://ibb.co/9YBGw26

Comment: Ну что же - руки отрывать за такое программирование - запуск не по правилам WP. Ищите по файлам, добавьте код запуска в вопрос, с указанием, на каком хуке это делает плагин. Тогда можно будет попытаться ответить.

Comment: Можете по подробнее описать ? Через поиск по всем файлам shift + ctrl + f ничего не дало. Ну а подгружает сам woocommerce.

Comment: Не так искали, знаичт. И это НЕ WooCoomerce, Там такого говнокода нет и быть не может. Тем более, с древними версиями jquery.

Comment: Да, Advanced Custom Fields PRO

Comment: Там тоже нет такого кода